# Multi dictionary incrementation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create an dictionary in this format:

```
stats_dict = {
'num_lines': 9,
'by_exts': {
    'py': {
        'files': 4            **
        'percent': 60
    },
    'html': {
        'files': 3            **
        'percent': 40
    }
}}
```

At the 'files' step I can't increment the value. I use the following method in a loop to do the operation.

```
self.stats_dict['by_exts'][ext_file]['files'] = self.stats_dict['by_exts'][ext_file].setdefault('files', 0) + 1
```

Where is my problem ?

Comment: Please post any error messages or debugging you've done to give us a hand in helping you out

Comment: I have no error but the 'files' value stay at 1

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
def incr_dict(d, key, amt=1, default=0):
    d[key] = d.get(key, default) + amt

incr_dict(self.stats_dict['by_exts'][ext_file], "files")
```

Comment: Always the same trouble